# $C^{\infty}$-Diffeomorphism between a normed space and its open unit ball

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, normed-spaces

On $\mathbb R^n$, the open unit ball is known to be $C^{\infty}$-diffeomorphic to the whole space, for any norm.

Let $(E,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ be a normed vector space. Is it still true that the open unit ball $B$ of $E$ is $C^\infty$-diffeomorphic to $E$?

Remarks:

- The map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{1+\Vert x \Vert} x$ is a bijection from $E$ to $B$, but is not, in general, a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism.
- As shown in the comments, if the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ comes from an inner product, then $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\Vert x \Vert^2}}x$ is a $C^\infty$-diffeomorphism.

Comment: Are we talking about finite dimensional spaces, or general normed spaces?

Comment: general normed spaces

Comment: If the norm is $\|\cdot\|$, look at $f(x) = \frac{x}{1 + \|x\|}$

Comment: sorry I forgot the symbol $C^\infty$ ,  ur f is not $ C^\infty$

Comment: Something like $f(x) = \tan (\pi \|x\| /2) x$ for $x$ in the ball (or an adapted version) should work I guess

Comment: Thank you i will check if it works

Comment: The issue is that norms are not smooth in general, so some effort is needed in finessing this. For a Hilbert space $H$, the mapping $x\mapsto \frac{x}{\sqrt{1-\|x\|^2}}$ of the open unit ball centered at the origin, $B_1(0)$ to $H$ is smooth, with smooth inverse $y\mapsto \frac{y}{\sqrt{1+\|y\|^2}}$. Here, we have smoothness, since $\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle$ (and inner products are continuous bilinear maps hence smooth, so composing with the diagonal mapping $x\mapsto (x,x)$ yields a smooth map). For more general Banach spaces (or even an equivalent norm on a Hilbert space) I'm not sure.

Comment: Didier why ur f is smooth

Comment: @Jane it is not (hence the bracketed comments and the word *should*).

Comment: I need an example of normed vector space, not $C^{\infty}$-diffeomorphic to the unit ball